# Integration of Javascript with Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, web

I am rewriting an existing Java-based website in Python. After much research, I've settled on using Django and have so far made some good progress with the project.

I am, however, stuck trying to use some of the codes from the previous website. I am especially interested in using the `scripts.js` file which seems to have all the necessary JavaScript functions for the website, but not sure how to integrate it with my Django project.

Would I be able to just simply put this file in my `static` folder and refer to the functions from individual apps? If so, how would I call the functions? Would I have to make any changes to the file given that it now has to work with a Python-based website, as opposed to a Java-based website?

I'm also attaching a snippet of the `scripts.js` file to give you an idea of what the functions look like.

```
function gatewayGetAllInformation(){
    if(controlsLocked) {
        return;
    }
    lockControls();
    getFiles();
    gatewayGetShifts();
    getCatNews();
    getDepNews();
    getSales();
    getPermanentSales();
    adminGetUsers();
    unlockControls();
};

function gatewayGetShifts(){
    var url = root +"/AjaxResponder?action=getShifts";
    var xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
    xmlHttp.onreadystate = function() {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
            if(xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                var shiftsHTML =gatewayParseShifts(xmlHttp.responseXML);
                setInnerHTML("upcomingShiftsList",shiftsHTML); // added semicolon
            }
            else {
                setInnerHTML("upcomingShiftsList", "Error Getting Users");
            }
        }
    };
    xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
```

Thanks!

Comment: "Java-based website in Python" Do you mean you are using Jython?

Comment: @NoctisSkytower I meant I am writing a website in Python based off of an existing website that's written in Java! Sorry I didn't make myself clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put your javascript files in the static folder.

```
<!-- on top of the template file -->
{% load static %}

<!-- Where you want to load the javascript file template file -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'path/to/your/file.js' %}"></script>
```

`path/to/your/file.js` is a path relative to the `static` folder.

You should use [django-compressor](http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to minify your files on production environment.

As long as the routes you defined in the Django app are the same that in the Java app for the AJAX calls, you shouldn't have to change the content of your javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to put your `script.js` in your `/static/` folder.

```
static/
  js/
    script.js
```

In your templates you call it

```
...
<script src={% static 'js/script.js' %}></script>
...
```

And that's all, you are able to use `gatewayGetAllInformation` and `gatewayGetShifts` functions.

But keep in mind update the constants values inside `script.js`